# Several questions about migrating to XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, languages, babel, polyglossia

I am using LaTeX for years now but I am considering to migrate to XeLaTeX.

The main reason for this change is the `babel` package which change a lot the layout of my documents according to my language (French). For example, the itemize environment in LaTeX/Babel (in French) is completely different from the original (LaTeX/Babel/English). I prefer the original layout and I don't like the changes made by babel authors of the French option<sup>1</sup>. XeLaTeX (with Polyglossia and French language selected) does not change the layout (AFAIK).

For example, here are two screenshots. At the left, there is the LaTeX/Babel/French way of itemize. At the right, there is the same text with XeLaTeX/polyglossia/French. For me, there are no doubts the second (right side) is better.

[image: LaTeX/babel/French][image: XeLaTeX]

**However**, I have several questions about XeLaTeX. I don't know it at all, so please excuse the naivety.

1. Is the default font in XeLaTeX the same than the one in LaTeX? In my screenshot the XeLaTeX font seems a little bit thicker. 
   -> Related question : is it still usefull to call `lmodern` package with XeLaTeX?
2. Is the [`csquotes` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) still working with XeLaTeX?
3. For writing with XeLaTeX, I add these three packages calls after the document class : `fontspec`, `xunicode`, `polyglossia` (with the command    `\setmainlanguage{french}`). Is it sufficient? Do I miss something?
4. With the three package mentioned in question 3, do I have correct ligature and hyphenation for French?

I am also interested by documentations explaining how to migrate from LaTeX to XeLaTeX.

---

<sup>1. I believe it is not the job of the language package to decide the layout of the document.</sup>

Comment: The `french` option to `babel` actually *does* change the document layout, as you observe; but these changes can be undone.

Comment: @egreg Of course you could undo what `babel` does but I believe it is not always simple. It seems to me it is easier to migrate to XeLaTeX (which is, anyway, more closely interconnected with `polyglossia`, the future of `babel`)...

Comment: Is `\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}` that difficult? `;-)`

Comment: As a data point, I use `csquotes` a *ton* and have been using XeTeX for nearly six months now—I've never had an issue.

Comment: I just checked the French module for babel and it is now actively developped (see [the website](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/index.html). So I will probably still use babel instead of polyglossia (thanks @egreg).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default font for `fontspec` is Latin Modern; by itself, XeLaTeX doesn't change the standard font layout of LaTeX.

Now to your questions.

1. Don't trust screenshots too much. This is what I get with `pdflatex`

   [image: pdflatex]

   and this is what I get with `xelatex`

   [image: xelatex]

   The source file is

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{ifxetex}
   \ifxetex
     \usepackage{fontspec}
     \usepackage{polyglossia}
     \setmainlanguage{french}
   \else
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[french]{babel}
     \usepackage{lmodern}
   \fi

   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}
   \noindent
   Typeset with \ifxetex\verb|xelatex|\else\verb|pdflatex|\fi\\
   \lipsum[2]
   \end{document}
   ```

   The difference you see probably depends on the PDF viewer and its treatment of OpenType fonts.
2. Yes, `csquotes` works also with XeLaTeX. It could have some glitches, though. Without any clear example it's difficult to say.
3. Don't load `xunicode`. It's already loaded by `fontspec`.
4. Yes. You lose of course some features of the French module for `babel`. Check the documentation.

Just for information, calling

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
```

restores the standard layout. If you only want the standard `itemize` environment, call

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{
  ReduceListSpacing=false,
  StandardItemizeEnv=true,
  StandardItemLabels=true
}
```

Comment: you say (of `babel`) “it’s not the business of a language package to change layout”.  but `babel` wasn’t originally designed as a _language_ package — it was supposed to provide typesetting to match national styles.  of course this will often change the language used, but layout changes aren't there because of the language — in your case, you are seeing a french typesetting style (for example, with thin spaces between text and following punctuation).  i have no idea whether this is current style, but the code was written (and is now managed) by french people, so it stands a good chance.

Comment: It *is* the style elaborated by generations of french typographers and it corresponds to the recommendations of the ‘Imprimerie Nationale’. It can be slightly modified in case of special needs, of course

Comment: @Bernard Perhaps babel French style is what is recommended by some institution. However, when you see the itemize environment (for example) with no space between items or between item and the previous/next paragraph, it just appears for me as bad typography.

Comment: According to the [documentation of `frenchb`](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb-doc.pdf), `StandardLayout=true` restores not only the itemize environment but also first paragraph indent and footnotes.

Comment: If one would only to have the LaTeX default behavior for itemize environment, he should use the options : `ReduceListSpacing=false`, `StandardItemizeEnv=true` and `StandardItemLabels=true`.

Comment: I think  ‘no space betweens items’ is also a cultural matter. The default in frenchb is for ordinary text, not textbooks, as you may have in a novel, in literary essays. In my opinion the systematic use of bullets make your text look more or less like a presentation.

Comment: For my eyes, bullets and lot of spaces, that is the bad typography.